# Reading unknown data size using recv

Tags: c, sockets

I have implemented a (POSIX socket) client that sent an HTTP GET request to the specified website and parsed the http response into a source code.

Those specified websites are dynamic length, each of those websites are different sizes.
How could I know how much bytes do I should allocate in order to receive all data?

I think about chunks receiving - receive every time 512 chunks of data, parse then save them into a file.

Are you guys have efficient solutions?

Comment: what do you want to do with these websites?  E.g. storing them to disk or handling as a stream does not require dynamic memory allocations, while analyzing them in memory does.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP includes a length field!

Read some reasonable amount of bytes until you find `Content-Lenght: <len>` and then allocate a buffer to hold that exact amount.

Comment: `Content-Length` is optional; code must honor it (e.g. read not more data than given) but it must be also prepared to read until end-of-stream.

Comment: You still don't know the length of the header; And chunked encoding doesn't have content-length at all;

Comment: it seems like my solution is the best efficient way to do it.

Comment: 512 is a bit small.  I would go with 4K.

Comment: The content length is not only optional, it's untrustworthy, as RFC 1122 stated "Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send".